# how to set <spring:message> code with variable

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I want to set the code of  with variable.

for example, in jsp file

```
var code = getCodeResourceDynamically(value);

var msg = '<spring:message code="' + code + '"/>';
```

I can see an error message ' No message found under code '' + code + ''  on console. It seems that spring reads the name of variable, not value of variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you use JSTL?

Comment: yes. is it possible with JSTL?>

Answer (score 0):

Here it's something that I think it will help you:

```
   <body>
      <c:set var = "salary" scope = "session" value = "${2000*2}"/>
      <c:out value = "${salary}"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

I hope it'll help you :)

Here are more details: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm

Comment: I use the code above in jqGrid -> formatter, which is (I guess) impossible with html

Comment: I'm afraid i don't have an answer for this but you can try and check